# PHP RSA Enryption Always Returns "AAAAAAA"

Tags: php, laravel, encryption, rsa, phpseclib

I'm trying to encrypt a message using phpseclib. Below is the method that encrypts it:

```
function RSAEncrypt($data, $publicKey)
{
    $rsa = new \Crypt_RSA();

    $rsa->loadKey($publicKey);

    $rsa->setEncryptionMode(CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_PKCS1);

    $encryptedData = $rsa->encrypt($data);

    $encodedData = base64_encode($encryptedData);
    return $encodedData;

}
```

the code that encrypt message

```
        $client_key = 123456789;
    $random_str = rand();
    $aes_password = $client_key.'-'.$random_str;
    $public_key =  file_get_contents('keys/public.xml');
    $ecrypted_password =  RSAEncrypt($aes_password, $public_key);
```

but no matter the message the $aes_password that i passed , the $ecrypted_password output is always

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAE= ◀"
```

I tried to decrypt it using the private key to see if its valid anyways but i always gets Decryption Error so i figured maybe the error is with the encryption

Comment: I can't see any error checking in your code. Does `$rsa->encrypt()` return `false`, perhaps? What have you done so far to debug this issue?

Comment: My first instinct was that your server is haunted, and someone is screaming... More seriously, that base64 string decodes to a long string of zero bits followed by a single 1 bit. That's _not_ the same as `base64_encode(1);` which would be `MQ==`, or `base64_encode(false);` which would be an empty string.

Comment: @r3mainer, what i have noticed so far is , no matter the data i am encrypting , the output is always the same , both on localhost and live server

Comment: @IMSoP , i am just confused

Comment: AAAAA is what you get when you do `base64_encode("\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0")`. Probably some of the data isn't being passed correctly. My recommendation: before you call `$rsa->encrypt($data)` I'd do `echo $rsa;` to make sure the RSA key was loaded correctly and `var_dump($data)` to make sure that the plaintext was being passed correctly

Comment: @neubeert, the output without base64 encode is \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x .

Comment: @code_anic - did you do `echo $rsa;` before calling `$rsa->encrypt($data);` and `var_dump($data);` as well? How did those look?